# What is the differences between pushtopics and platform events?

Tags: pushtopic, platform-event

what is the differences between pushtopics and platform events?
When i can use the pushtopics and when i can use the platform events?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this it is best to take a look at the [following resource](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_intro_other_events.htm).
You can then further deepdive in the Platform Events vs Streaming.